# CentOS6.3にsysstat10以上をインストールしたい

Tags: centos

現状CentOS6.3でsysstatの9.0.4がインストールされています。
sarのログをエクセルで整形して比較したりしたいので、sadfでtsv形式で出力したいのですが、
そのときに9.0.4では「sadf」の「-T」オプションがないようでtsv形式で出力はできるのですが、時刻がわかりづらい形式で出力されてしまいます。

別の環境でsysstat10以上を使えば、-Tオプションを使うことができるのを確認したので、centOS6.3にsysstatの10以上にアップグレードしたいと考えていますが、これは可能でしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CentOS(及びそのベースとなるRHEL)は比較的安定した古いバージョンのパッケージを採用するディストリビューションなので、sysstatも公式のrpmパッケージとしては既にインストール済みの9.0.4までしか用意されていません (CentOS7向けは10.1.5)。

代わりに [ソースコード](https://github.com/sysstat/sysstat) から自分でコンパイルすることで最新版を利用できますが、sysstatの配布アーカイブにはspecファイルも含まれているので、rpmパッケージを作成しておくと管理が楽になると思います。

CentOS6の環境が無かったので以下は7で実行していますが、基本的には同じ流れでOKなはずです。
(事前に`gcc`や`make`などのコンパイル環境や、`rpmbuild`コマンドのインストールが必要となります)

```
$ curl -L -O https://github.com/sysstat/sysstat/archive/v12.1.6.tar.gz
$ rpmbuild -ta sysstat-12.1.6.tar.gz
$ sudo rpm -Uvh ~/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/sysstat-12.1.6-1.x86_64.rpm
```

参考: [tarボールからRPMファイルを作成するには](http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/flinux/rensai/linuxtips/486mkrpmfromtar.html)

Comment: rpmパッケージとして用意されているバージョンよりも新しいバージョンも利用できる可能性があることが知ることができてよかったです。
結局入っているバージョンのままksarというグラフ作成ツールを利用することにしたので、教えていただいた方法を試すことはできていないのですが、別の環境でsysstatを利用する際にはこちらの方法を試させていただこうと思います。ありがとうございました。